# error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle'

Tags: python, opencv

I use this code to generate annotation on images to make identification with opencv

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
def geration_bb (img, threshold, rect_th, path):
    boxes = prediction(img, threshold)
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        cv2.rectangle(img,boxes[i][0],boxes[i][1],color =(255, 0, 0),thickness=rect_th)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()
    # for to save the prediction figure 
    io.imsave(path, img)
```

the error generated

```
error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - argument for rectangle() given by name ('color') and position (3)
>  - argument for rectangle() given by name ('color') and position (3)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Ensure the points are of type `int`

Comment: you didn't search for the error message. please review [ask]. and your code was broken. in python, indentation is syntax, meaning you must not get that wrong or else it means something entirely. I guessed what you meant it to be.

Comment: I couldn't make any changes, I tried to pass the coordinates to int but it wasn't